# When do phases not exist for spectrograms?

Tags: phase, spectrogram, stft

I have been reading a paper on the ["Single pass spectrogram inversion"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7251907)

and I came across this in the Introduction part.

> In many applications, the analysis and modification of the Short-Time
>   Fourier Transform (STFT) and the Short-Time Fourier Transform
>   Magnitude (STFTM) of speech and audiosignals are necessary. These
>   applications include, but are not limited to audio enhancement,
>   reverberation analysis, time and pitch modification, and noise
>   cancellation. **Phases are either lost, become meaningless as the
>   spectral representations are manipulated, or simply do not exist for
>   artificially constructed spectrograms.** The objective, then, is to use
>   these spectral representations to generate a real-valued signal that
>   corresponds as closely as possible to the original spectrograms.

I do not understand why phases do not exist for artificially constructed spectrograms. A spectrogram simply represents what frequencies exist for a certain duration of time, right? So technically, we could just have zero phase for all the frequencies involved and it would be a realizable signal.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: That literally just means someone created a picture or a 2D function, said "this is a spectrogram", but didn't specify what the phase at each point was.

Comment: But even if they did not specify it, why can't an arbitrary phase be assigned to the spectrogram?

Comment: it can. That's not what the sentence is about. Prior to assignment, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, got it. I just misunderstood what it meant then